# How to automate the conversion of PPT into PDFs?

Tags: python, pdf, automation, file-conversion, python-pptx

I currently have a template for certificate in PPT format and wish to convert (or print) it to PDF.

I have a python list of people names that I am passing to python in the form of a list.

I need help with library and code to write a python script to automate this process by using a loop to edit the ppt with the names in the list and export the ppts to generate PDFs iteratively

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off converting to PDF first with a placeholder text and then try to replace the text in the PDF using pdf-redactor: https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor

A more reliable and future-proof option would be to replicate the template in Latex, where you can then very easily substitute the text.